# How can I make a query for each month 7:15-12:15 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I found two similar answers

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   fd_member 
WHERE  From_unixtime(Unix_timestamp(add_time), '%h') >= 8 
       AND From_unixtime(Unix_timestamp(add_time), '%h') < 12 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(add_time, CHAR(10))
```

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM   fd_member f 
WHERE  Date(f.date) >= Date('2013-10-01') 
       AND Date(f.date) < Date('2013-11-01') 
       AND Hour(f.date) >= Hour('8:00:00') 
       AND Hour(f.date) < Hour('12:00:00')
```

But they are not accurate to the minute.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   fd_member f 
WHERE  Date(f.date) >= Date('2013-10-01') 
       AND Date(f.date) < Date('2013-11-01') 
       AND Time(f.date) >= Time('7:15:00') 
       AND Time(f.date) < Time('12:15:00')
```

Should work. Give it a go. if not could you provide an SQL fiddle with some sample data and what you expect out